# Network card for motherboard Pine Row

Tags: network-adapter, firewall

I need to find a network card that is compatible with the motherboard pine row, this board is in a firewall, the client prefers to buy a network card that has two network outputs and is pci-express, but this motherboard pine row is desktop, which takes some board options by being server boards.

The model of the card is the same, or at least very similar to that of the advertisement:
`https://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-Pro-300...-2-Duo-E7500-2-93GHz-CPU-/361738139160?_ul=BR`
The network cards I considered interesting by the specification are:

Common PCI Intel:
`https: //producto.mercadolivre.com.br...-pci-pro1000mt-chipset-82546gb-_JM? source = gps`

PCI-Express Chinese brand:
`https: //producto.mercadolivre.com.br...18dc4fd046bb235b6ae5a022409fd921&noIndex=true`

Which of these two would be best for the firewall? Does it have much difference of performance PCI-Express card for PCI Common?

I'm also accepting suggestions from other boards.

Comment: By Pine Row, do you mean the motherboard out of an HP Pro 3000, or the system as a whole? And what's this about firewall?

Comment: the two links are broken. and well, there's only a handful of actual chips you'd find. I'd note though that's a *really* old PC.

Comment: @JMY1000 It's a HP Pro 3000 PC that I need to put a network card in it.